# Unable to install flex - Many errors: E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap

Tags: swap, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bison

Unable to install flex - There were many errors:
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 m4 amd64 1.4.18-5ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/m4/m4_1.4.18-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap.

Comment: There servers might be down in your region. Click on those links and check if your browser can reach the site. Wait a few hours and see if the servers come back up